# Application crashes on selecting spinner item?

Tags: android, jquery, spinner, android-alertdialog

In my application, I'm providing various `Templates` for the `Text Message Body`, as `spinner list items` , that can be selected and user can send them instead of typing `message`, But the problem is when user open the menu item to select template the `application crashes`. `Spinner` i've put in `alert dialog box` which is accessible through menu item.

**Code for dialog box ***

```
AlertDialog.Builder rdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            rdialog.setTitle("Select Message");
            rdialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rptsetting,null);

            final Spinner fSpinner = (Spinner)alertView.findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
            String providers[] ={"Busy", "Good Morning", "In office"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,providers);
            fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
            fSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent, View arg1,
                        int pos, long arg3) {

                    String selectedItem = fSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if(selectedItem.equals("Busy")){
                        body = "Currently Busy call again later, Thanks";
                    }

                    if(selectedItem.equals("Good Morning")){
                        body = "A very Good Morning, Have a nice day";
                    }

                    if(selectedItem.equals("In office")){
                        body = "Currently in office";
                    }   

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent) {
                }
            });
rdialog.setView(alertView);
            rdialog.setNeutralButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();   
                    }
                });

            AlertDialog rdialog1 = rdialog.create();
            rdialog1.show();
```

I've define `body` as global String so that it can be accessible by `Sms Manager` to use it as body of message to be send. 
Log Cat
[image: Log cat]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ Simple Plan check my edits for log cat

Comment: @A what is body? is an String? then initialized it.

Comment: @ Simple Plan `body` is message body variable which is used by `Sms Manager`

Comment: Your `body` is mostly the cause of the problem. Check that it is not null first.

Comment: @Neoh i've declare `body` as `String body;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Correct this one like under `onItemSelected(.....)`

```
  String selectedItem = aparent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

  if(selectedItem.equals("Busy")){
  body = "Currently Busy call again later, Thanks";
   }
  if(selectedItem.equals("Good Morning")){
  body = "A very Good Morning, Have a nice day";
   }
  if(selectedItem.equals("In office")){
  body = "Currently in office";
  }
```

And also cross check your `body` variable is not null

Comment: i've declare `body` as `String body;`

Comment: @Androidbeginner try this first and give me feedback

Comment: already tried, even if i want to concatenate edittext value with given string like some text with given template code - `"Currently in office"+edittext.getText().toString()` it shows error.

Comment: @Androidbeginner but i can't see any `EditText` into your code? where it comes from?

Comment: earlier i tried with edittext but it won't worked so i removed it.

Comment: can you help me one thing, by default its selecting `"Busy" as template`, is there any way so i'll won't select any template by default and shows `-Select-` in spinner

Comment: @Androidbeginner ya off course but plz wait i'll come back in 10 min

Comment: @Androidbeginner you cant's do this but instead of u can set `TextView` as a `title` and set `spinner` to `android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true"` : more info go to: [http://androidituts.com/android-spinner-tutorial/](http://androidituts.com/android-spinner-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

To get selected item from Spinner try using `getItemAtPosition` method of `AdapterView`. as:

```
@Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent, View arg1,
                        int pos, long arg3) {
 String selectedItem = aparent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
 //...your code...
}
```